# Creating a small encrypted string in PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am looking to create a small encrypted string, like the referral strings used by Twitpic or bit.ly, for a website I am working on for referral purposes.  Any of the built-in functions like MD5 and mcrypt each make strings that are too long for my purposes.

Is there an easy way to create a string like this?  Thanks.

Comment: md5 is not an encryption algorithm,  although you are probably looking for a message digest function like md5.

Comment: Do you need to be able to *de* crypt it? Or are you just looking for a small random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, I'm guessing that you just want to have a short string of text/numbers that uniquely refers to a username, an image, an URL or something similar.

A solution would be just to generate a random string and map that to the user/image/URL in your database. Here's the random string function we use. You can adjust `$chars` depending on your application. It can generate a short 5-letter string like twitpic if necessary.

```
function randstr($length) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $chooselength = strlen($chars);
    $string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < ((int) $length); $i++) {
        $string .= $chars[mt_rand() % $chooselength];
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, although I'd add upper and lower case to this as well - I believe services like Twitpic use the case of their random string to generate more space within a limited-length string.

Answer (score 1):

What about [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) ?
It is not what you really asked, but according to the examples you gave, it could be what you're looking for